# Different size items in a VariableSizedWrapGrid

Tags: layout, winrt-xaml

The app I'm working on uses a grouped GridView. Different templates are being used for different items on display and this is causing me an issue with the layout because the VariableSizedWrapGrid sets the row & column sizes based on the first item in each group.

I've tried to use the commonly-suggested solution of PrepareContainerForItemOverride and I'm encountering two problems:

1. It seems that I can only adjust the height & width around multiples of the column & row spans. That can leave me with quite a bit of wasted space if, say, item #2 needs to have 1.5 x the row height of item #1. I also seem to have to "guess" at what the most appropriate multiple is, which doesn't seem to be appropriate when apps are supposed to scale dynamically.
2. If I get the multiples too big, the content is horizontally & vertically centred. I've tried changing the alignment from stretch to left in various places but I cannot find which control property to set to get this to work.

Is there a better way of adjusting the item sizes than grid spans? If there isn't, is there a better way for me to lay out my content with variably sized items?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/ includes WrapPanel which does the job perfectly. It stacks the individual items either horizontally or vertically and wraps onto the next row/column as required.